# Run php file when submit button in another html file

Tags: php, html, toggle, execute

I would like to work on registration process for which with the help of Google and Youtube i have created "Sign-in & Sing-up" page togather with toggle option however unable to run registration.php file once user provide registration info at login.html file. Codes are as follows :

```
<form id="login" class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="input-field" placeholder="User Id" required>
    <input type="password" class="input-field" placeholder="Enter Password" required>
    <input type="checkbox" class="check-box"><span>Remember Password</span>
    <button type="submit" class="submit-btn">Sign-In</button>
</form>

<form Id="register" class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="input-field" placeholder="User Id" required>
    <input type="email" class="input-field" placeholder="Email Id" required>
    <input type="password" class="input-field" placeholder="Enter Password" required>
    <input type="password" class="input-field" placeholder="Confirm Password" required>
    <input type="phone-number" class="input-field" placeholder="Mobile Number" required>
    <input type="checkbox" class="check-box"><span>I agree to the terms & conditions</span>
    <button type="submit" class="submit-btn">Sign-Up</button>
</form>
```

How to execute registration.php file when Sign-up button clicked at login.html file? Same goes for login option too.

Comment: Use `<form action="path_to/registration.php" method="get">` this.

Comment: I suggest reading about [`<form>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form), specifically the `action` and `method` attribute

Answer (score 0):

The method attribute specifies how to send form-data (the form-data is sent to the page specified in the action attribute).

The form-data can be sent as URL variables (with method="get") or as HTTP post transaction (with method="post").

check here for more details [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_method.asp)

```
<form id="login" class="input-group" method="POST" action="file_path/login.php">
    <input type="text" class="input-field" placeholder="User Id" required>
    <input type="password" class="input-field" placeholder="Enter Password" required>
    <input type="checkbox" class="check-box"><span>Remember Password</span>
    <input type="submit" class="submit-btn" value="Sign-In">
</form>

<form Id="register" class="input-group" method="POST" action="file_path/register.php">
    <input type="text" class="input-field" placeholder="User Id" required>
    <input type="email" class="input-field" placeholder="Email Id" required>
    <input type="password" class="input-field" placeholder="Enter Password" required>
    <input type="password" class="input-field" placeholder="Confirm Password" required>
    <input type="phone-number" class="input-field" placeholder="Mobile Number" required>
    <input type="checkbox" class="check-box"><span>I agree to the terms & conditions</span>
    <input type="submit" class="submit-btn" value="Sign-Up">
</form>
```

**EDIT according to your comment**

replace button with input type="submit"
and place @ before the php variable so you wont get undefined error notice(@ is used to avoid error notice)

```
<div class="header"> 
    <h2>Register here</h2> 
</div> 
<form method="post" action="register.php"> 
    <?php include('errors.php'); ?> 
    <div class="input-group"> 
        <label>Username</label> 
        <input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo @$username; ?>"> 
    </div> 
    <div class="input-group"> 
            <label>Email</label> 
            <input type="email" name="email" value="<?php echo @$email; ?>"> 
        </div> 
        <div class="input-group"> 
            <label>Password</label> 
            <input type="password" name="password_1"> 
        </div> 
        <div class="input-group"> 
            <label>Confirm Password</label> 
            <input type="password" name="password_2"> 
        </div>


<div class="input-group"> 
    <label>Mobile number</label> 
    <input type="number" name="mobile" value="<?php echo @$mobile; ?>"> 
</div> 
<div class="input-group"> 
    <input type="submit" class="btn" name="reg_user" value="Sign-Up">
</div> 
</form>
```

create register.php file
and in register.php

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "username", "password", "dbname") or trigger_error("Unable to connect to the database");
    if(isset($_POST['reg_user'])){
        $name = $_POST['username']; //here "username" is what you defined in the "name" field of input form
    //define other variables
        //write your own sql query , here is an example
        $query = "INSERT INTO table(name) VALUES(?)";
        $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($con);
        if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt,$query)){
            echo "Error";
        }else{
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"s",$name);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Good job! Escaping is not needed so I removed it. You should also avoid check the return value of `prepare()`. Instead enable error reporting.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to add `method="POST"` and `action="path/function.php"` and `name="desiredName"`in your forms like this:

```
<form id="login" class="input-group" method="POST" action="file_path/login.php">
    <input type="text" class="input-field" placeholder="User Id" name ="user" required>
    <input type="password" class="input-field" placeholder="Enter Password" name="password" required>
    <input type="checkbox" class="check-box"><span>Remember Password</span>
    <button type="submit" class="submit-btn">Sign-In</button>
</form>
```

And then in PHP to "catch" the data from the post, you'll use something like this:

```
$this->getpost['user'];
```

Or

```
$_POST['user'];
```

Comment: Thanks Mathall
Followed this <form Id="register" class="input-group" method="POST" action="file_path/register.php"> Don't know where to place $_POST['user']; in register.php file. What is 'user'?
Now after submit register.php pages opens without saving user details in database. Seems linking is still missing. Please help.

Comment: @RaviPrakashShukla "user" in this case is the "name" of the field that you're posting User Id with from your html form to your backend PHP, you will have to make sure it saves in the database etc aswell of course but that's another question